# using base64 encoded path parameter in the REST URI with the API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I have a new API endpoint that has a base64 encoded path parameter. It looks like this:

```
/user/save/:userEmail
```

userEmail is base64 encoded.

The authorizer fails to approve the token for this endpoint but works for other endpoints. why is that? Is there anything wrong with using base64 encoded path param while using API gateway.

lambda authorizer looks as follows:

```
export async function tokenAuthorizer(event: APIGatewayTokenAuthorizerEvent): Promise<APIGatewayAuthorizerResult> {
  const {authorizationToken, methodArn } = event;
  const jwtHandler = new JWT();
  let valid = jwtHandler.decodeToken(authorizationToken);
  if (valid){
    valid = await jwtHandler.validateToken();
  }
  return jwtHandler.generatePolicy(valid, methodArn);
}

  generatePolicy(allowed: boolean, methodArn: string): APIGatewayAuthorizerResult {
    const effect = allowed ? 'Allow' : 'Deny';
    const policy: APIGatewayAuthorizerResult = {
      principalId: this.principalId,
      policyDocument: {
        Version: '2012-10-17',
        Statement: [
          {
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
            Effect: effect,
            Resource: methodArn,
          },
        ]
      },
      context: this.requestEnrich
    };

    return policy;
  }
```

Comment: One the URL length can be super long. >2000 chars Probably unlikely since an email isn't that long.

Have you logged the value of the decoded JWT handler?

Comment: base64 values aren't really going to make a good path parameter because base64 allows characters such as `+` and `/`.  Are you making sure you are URL-encoding the base64 encoded path parameter?  Why not just skip the base64 encoding and just accept a url-encoded email address?